Recreated Battle City Arcade Game in Java Swing - Enemy Teleportation Issue
I have recreated the Battle City arcade game using Java Swing. I have successfully implemented the grid, player movement, and bullet mechanics. I have also created an enemy (a small square for now) and used the A* search algorithm to move the enemy from the start to the goal position. The enemy reaches the goal position and then is supposed to set the start position to the goal position and pick a new random goal position on any open tiles on the grid. However, the enemy does not follow the expected behavior; instead, it instantly teleports to the goal and calls the pickNewPosition method again and again. I need help identifying and resolving this issue.
GamePanel.java
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import ai.Node;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    //GAME SCREEN PROPERTIES
    final int ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE = 8;
    final int SCALE = 3;
    final int TILE_SIZE = ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE * SCALE;
    
    public final int SCREEN_COL = 26;
    public final int SCREEN_ROW = 28;
    final int SCREEN_WIDTH = TILE_SIZE * SCREEN_COL;
    final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = TILE_SIZE * SCREEN_ROW;
    
    Thread GAME_THREAD;
    KeyController keyC = new KeyController();
    BufferedImage BRICK_IMAGE, STONE_IMAGE;
    
    //PLAYER PROPERTIES
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int newPosX = posX;
    int newPosY = posY;
    int PLAYER_SPEED = 3;
    BufferedImage TANK_UP, TANK_DOWN, TANK_LEFT, TANK_RIGHT, CURRENT_IMAGE, BULLET_UP, 
                BULLET_DOWN, BULLET_RIGHT, BULLET_LEFT, BULLET_IMAGE, EXPLOSION_IMAGE;
    
    //BULLET PROPERTIES
    int bulletX;
    int bulletY;
    boolean isShooting = false;
    String lastDirection;
    
    ArrayList<Integer> openCol = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> openRow = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Random random = new Random();
    Node[][] node = new Node[SCREEN_COL][SCREEN_ROW];
    Node START_NODE, GOAL_NODE, CURRENT_NODE;
    ArrayList<Node> OPEN_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Node> CHECKED_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Node> PATH = new ArrayList<>();
    
    boolean GOAL_REACHED = false;
    
    int GOAL_POSITION;
    int START_POSITION;
    int step = 0;
    
    //ENEMY POSITION
    int enemyX;
    int enemyY;
    
    int currentIndex = 0;
    int timer = 0;
    
    boolean currentlyMoving = false;
    
    char[][] GAME_MAP = {
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','2','2','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','2','2','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1'},
            {'2','2','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','0','2','2'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','3','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','5','5','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','5','5','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
    };
    
    public void getSpawnPoint() {
        for(int i = 0; i < GAME_MAP.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < GAME_MAP[i].length; j++) {
                if(GAME_MAP[i][j] == '3') {
                    posX = j * TILE_SIZE;
                    posY = i * TILE_SIZE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initializeOpenPosition() {
        for (int col = 0; col < SCREEN_COL; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < SCREEN_ROW; row++) {
                if (GAME_MAP[row][col] == '0') {
                    openCol.add(col); // Store the column index
                    openRow.add(row); // Store the row index
                }
            }
        }

        GOAL_POSITION = random.nextInt(openCol.size());
        START_POSITION = random.nextInt(openCol.size());
    }
    public void initializeNodes() {
        for(int col = 0; col < SCREEN_COL; col++) {
            for(int row = 0; row < SCREEN_ROW; row++) {
                node[col][row] = new Node(col, row);
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < SCREEN_COL; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < SCREEN_ROW; row++) {
                if (GAME_MAP[row][col] == '1' || GAME_MAP[row][col] == '2') {
                    // Set the current node as solid
                    setSolidNode(col, row);
                }
            }
        }
        
        //SET START NODE AND GOAL NODE
        setStartNode(openCol.get(START_POSITION), openRow.get(START_POSITION));
        setGoalNode(openCol.get(GOAL_POSITION), openRow.get(GOAL_POSITION));
        setCostOnNodes();
        autoSearch();
        
        setEnemySpawnpoint();
    }
    private void setStartNode(int col, int row) {
        node[col][row].setAsStart();
        START_NODE = node[col][row];
        CURRENT_NODE = START_NODE;
    }
    private void setGoalNode(int col, int row) {
        node[col][row].setAsGoal();
        GOAL_NODE = node[col][row];
    }
    private void setSolidNode(int col, int row) {
        node[col][row].setAsSolid();
    }
    private void setCostOnNodes() {
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        
        while(col < SCREEN_COL && row < SCREEN_ROW) {
            getCost(node[col][row]);
            col++;
            if(col == SCREEN_COL) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
    }
    private void getCost(Node node) {
        int xDistance = Math.abs(node.col - START_NODE.col);
        int yDistance = Math.abs(node.row - START_NODE.row);
        node.gCost = xDistance + yDistance;
        
        xDistance = Math.abs(node.col - GOAL_NODE.col);
        yDistance = Math.abs(node.row - GOAL_NODE.row);
        node.hCost = xDistance + yDistance;
        
        node.fCost = node.gCost + node.hCost;
    }
    public void autoSearch() {
        while(GOAL_REACHED == false && step < 300) {
            int col = CURRENT_NODE.col;
            int row = CURRENT_NODE.row;
            
            CURRENT_NODE.setAsChecked();
            CHECKED_LIST.add(CURRENT_NODE);
            OPEN_LIST.remove(CURRENT_NODE);
            
            if(row - 1 >= 0) {
                OPEN_NODE(node[col][row - 1]);
            }
            if(col - 1 >= 0) {
                OPEN_NODE(node[col-1][row]);
            }
            if(row + 1 < SCREEN_ROW) {
                OPEN_NODE(node[col][row+1]);
            }
            if(col + 1 < SCREEN_COL) {
                OPEN_NODE(node[col+1][row]);
            }
            
            int bestNodeIndex = 0;
            int bestNodefCost = 999;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < OPEN_LIST.size(); i++) {
                if(OPEN_LIST.get(i).fCost < bestNodefCost) {
                    bestNodeIndex = 1;
                    bestNodefCost = OPEN_LIST.get(i).fCost;
                }
                else if(OPEN_LIST.get(i).fCost == bestNodefCost) {
                    if(OPEN_LIST.get(i).gCost < OPEN_LIST.get(bestNodeIndex).gCost) {
                        bestNodeIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            CURRENT_NODE = OPEN_LIST.get(bestNodeIndex);
            
            if(CURRENT_NODE == GOAL_NODE) {
                GOAL_REACHED = true;
                trackThePath();
            }
        }
        step++;
    }
    private void OPEN_NODE(Node node) {
        if(node.open == false && node.checked == false && node.solid == false) {
            node.setAsOpen();
            node.parent = CURRENT_NODE;
            OPEN_LIST.add(node);
        }
    }
    private void trackThePath() {
        Node CURRENT = GOAL_NODE;
        
        while(CURRENT != START_NODE) {
            CURRENT = CURRENT.parent;
            if(CURRENT != START_NODE) {
                PATH.add(node[CURRENT.col][CURRENT.row]);
            }
        }
        
        Collections.reverse(PATH);
    }
    private void setEnemySpawnpoint() {
        int x = START_NODE.getCol();
        int y = START_NODE.getRow();
        
        enemyX = x * TILE_SIZE;
        enemyY = y * TILE_SIZE;
    }
    private void pickNewPosition() {
        START_POSITION = GOAL_POSITION;
        GOAL_POSITION = random.nextInt(openCol.size());
        
        setStartNode(openCol.get(START_POSITION), openRow.get(START_POSITION));
        setGoalNode(openCol.get(GOAL_POSITION), openRow.get(GOAL_POSITION));
        setCostOnNodes();
        autoSearch();
        
        setEnemySpawnpoint();
    }
    
    public void START_GAME_THREAD() {
        GAME_THREAD = new Thread(this);
        GAME_THREAD.start();
    }
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyC);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(SCREEN_ROW, SCREEN_COL));
        
        try {
            BRICK_IMAGE = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/BRICK.png"));
            STONE_IMAGE = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/STONE_BRICK.png"));
            TANK_UP = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/TANK_UP.png"));
            TANK_DOWN = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/TANK_DOWN.png"));
            TANK_LEFT = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/TANK_LEFT.png"));
            TANK_RIGHT = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/TANK_RIGHT.png"));
            BULLET_UP = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/bullet_up.png"));
            BULLET_DOWN = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/bullet_down.png"));
            BULLET_LEFT = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/bullet_left.png"));
            BULLET_RIGHT = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/bullet_right.png"));
            EXPLOSION_IMAGE = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/explosion.png"));
            
            CURRENT_IMAGE = TANK_UP;
            BULLET_IMAGE = BULLET_UP;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getSpawnPoint();
        initializeOpenPosition();
        initializeNodes();
    }
    public void update() {
        newPosX = posX;
        newPosY = posY;
        
        if(!isShooting) {
            bulletX = posX + ((TILE_SIZE + 8) / 2);
            bulletY = posY + ((TILE_SIZE + 8) / 2);
        }
        
        if(keyC.UP_PRESSED) {
            newPosY -= PLAYER_SPEED;
            CURRENT_IMAGE = TANK_UP;
            
            if(!isShooting) {
                lastDirection = "up";
            }
        } else if(keyC.DOWN_PRESSED) {
            newPosY += PLAYER_SPEED;
            CURRENT_IMAGE = TANK_DOWN;
            
            if(!isShooting) {
                lastDirection = "down";
            }
        } else if(keyC.LEFT_PRESSED) {
            newPosX -= PLAYER_SPEED;
            CURRENT_IMAGE = TANK_LEFT;
            
            if(!isShooting) {
                lastDirection = "left";
            }
        } else if(keyC.RIGHT_PRESSED) {
            newPosX += PLAYER_SPEED;
            CURRENT_IMAGE = TANK_RIGHT;
            
            if(!isShooting) {
                lastDirection = "right";
            }
        }
        if(keyC.X_PRESSED) {
            isShooting = true;
        }
        if(isShooting) {
            if(lastDirection == "up") {
                BULLET_IMAGE = BULLET_UP;
                if(bulletY <= 0) {
                    isShooting = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    bulletY -= 3;
                }
            }
            if(lastDirection == "down") {
                BULLET_IMAGE = BULLET_DOWN;
                if(bulletY >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
                    isShooting = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    bulletY += 3;
                }
            }
            if(lastDirection == "left") {
                BULLET_IMAGE = BULLET_LEFT;
                if(bulletX <= 0) {
                    isShooting = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    bulletX -= 3;
                }
            }
            if(lastDirection == "right") {
                BULLET_IMAGE = BULLET_RIGHT;
                if(bulletX >= SCREEN_WIDTH) {
                    isShooting = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    bulletX += 3;
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle PLAYER = new Rectangle(newPosX, newPosY, TILE_SIZE + 15, TILE_SIZE + 15);
        Rectangle BULLET = new Rectangle(bulletX, bulletY, 8, 8);
        for(int i = 0; i < GAME_MAP.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < GAME_MAP[i].length; j++) {
                if(GAME_MAP[i][j] == '1') {
                    Rectangle TILE = new Rectangle(j * TILE_SIZE, i * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                    if(BULLET.intersects(TILE)) {
                        GAME_MAP[i][j] = '0';
                        isShooting = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    if(PLAYER.intersects(TILE)) {
                        return;
                    }
                } else if(GAME_MAP[i][j] == '2') {
                    Rectangle TILE = new Rectangle(j * TILE_SIZE, i * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                    if(PLAYER.intersects(TILE)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if(BULLET.intersects(TILE)) {
                        isShooting = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(newPosX < 0 || newPosX > SCREEN_WIDTH - (TILE_SIZE + 15)) {
            return;
        } 
        if(newPosY < 0 || newPosY > SCREEN_HEIGHT - (TILE_SIZE + 15)) {
            return;
        }
        
        timer++;
        if(timer > 14) {
            if(currentIndex < PATH.size()) {
                Node currentNode = PATH.get(currentIndex);
                int col = currentNode.col;
                int row = currentNode.row;
                
                int newX = col * TILE_SIZE;
                int newY = row * TILE_SIZE;
                
                enemyX = newX;
                enemyY = newY;
                
                currentIndex++;
                timer = 0;
            } else {
                pickNewPosition();
            }
        }
        
        posX = newPosX;
        posY = newPosY;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < GAME_MAP.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < GAME_MAP[i].length; j++) {
                if(GAME_MAP[i][j] == '1') {
                    g2.drawImage(BRICK_IMAGE,j * TILE_SIZE, i * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE,null);
                }
                if(GAME_MAP[i][j] == '2') {
                    g2.drawImage(STONE_IMAGE,j * TILE_SIZE, i * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE,null);
                }
            }
        }
    
        g2.drawImage(BULLET_IMAGE, bulletX, bulletY, 8, 8, null);
        
        g2.drawImage(CURRENT_IMAGE, posX, posY, TILE_SIZE + 15, TILE_SIZE + 15, null);
        
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        for(int j = 0; j < openCol.size(); j++) {
            int col = openCol.get(GOAL_POSITION);
            int row = openRow.get(GOAL_POSITION);
            
            int x = col * TILE_SIZE;
            int y = row * TILE_SIZE;
            
            g2.fillRect(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
        }
        
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        for(int j = 0; j < openCol.size(); j++) {
            int col = openCol.get(START_POSITION);
            int row = openRow.get(START_POSITION);
            
            int x = col * TILE_SIZE;
            int y = row * TILE_SIZE;
            
            g2.fillRect(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
            
            
        }
        g2.drawImage(CURRENT_IMAGE, enemyX, enemyY, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/60; 
        double delta = 0; 
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); 
        long currentTime; 
        while(GAME_THREAD != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            if(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }

}

Node.java
package ai;

public class Node {

    public Node parent;
    public int col;
    public int row;
    public int gCost;
    public int hCost;
    public int fCost;
    public boolean start;
    public boolean goal;
    public boolean solid;
    public boolean open;
    public boolean checked;
    
    public Node(int col, int row) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }
    public void setAsStart() {
        start = true;
    }
    public void setAsGoal() {
        goal = true;
    }
    public void setAsSolid() {
        solid = true;
    }
    public void setAsOpen() {
        open = true;        
    }
    public void setAsChecked() {
        checked = true;
    }
    public void setAsPath() {
        
    }
    
     public int getCol() {
         return col;
     }
     public int getRow() {
         return row;
     }
}

As you can see on the pick new position code i tried to reset everything so that all the nodes are clean. I expected it to work but it seems not.

What happened when you set breakpoints and ran your code through the debugger?

it doesn't show an error message or anything, i think i made some logical error on the pick new position part of the code

All Swing calls need to be made on the AWT event dispatch thread. You cannot use a new Thread of your own. The best way to make sure your code runs in the proper thread is to make use of the javax.swing.Timer class (not java.util.Timer; that class will not run your code in the AWT event dispatch thread). Failure to follow Swing’s threading rules will lead to unpredictable behavior: things may fail all the time, or some of the time, or only in certain conditions or on some computers but not others.

i never used the timer class, it's just an unused import
